# USB won't format, shows as RAW in the disk management

Tags: usb, partitioning, gparted

I have a 32GB Kingston USB. It worked fine for almost a year now and I have filled it many times with data. Last time I connected it to my LCD TV to watch a movie and forgot it there for 2 weeks. Later I took it out and was able to access it but data would not copy to it so I tried formatting it and was left with a non-formatable USB.

I have tried almost everything, including formatting using the simple Windows format tool, Disk Management, gParted (Virtual Machine), the "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx" method (stuck for 24 hours), test-win, EVERYTHING I found on the internet. I tried searching for a Mass Media flash tool or whatever you call it and apparent it doesn't have one yet (SSS6698).

Right now it shows as RAW and won't format (on Windows, on gParted it says no partition table and when I try to create one for it using gParted, it just freezes). Using "fdisk -l" shows 0B free space.

[Disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk2rr.png)

Please help, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try gparted running on bare metal rather than in a VM.  if that doesn't work, you almost certainly just need to buy a new one.

http://download.cnet.com/GParted-Live/3000-2094_4-10698802.html